# Display : none css issue in Chrome,Mozilla, IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I've an issue with a button "Close" in a page. Below is the css applied for the button from css file.

```
NAVBUTTON {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Segoe UI;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
line-height: normal;
text-align: center;
height: 25px;
width: 120px;
}
```

When the page is rendered, an additional css element style as below is getting added due to which the button is not visible in the page.

```
element.style {
display: none;
}
```

I've this issue in IE11, Chrome, Mozilla browsers.

I can see the close button in IE 10 and other lower versions.

I found some answers to disable the javascript in browser and open the webpage, but if I disable javascript, page will not get rendered.

**Adding other issue with the same button**

I've solved the problem with displaying the button "Close" using the display:block!important css style.

**I'm facing a new issue:** On clicking the button, **no action is being performed**.

OnClick action given as window.top.close.

```
<input class="CloseButton" type="button" id="CloseButton" value="Close" onclick="window.top.close();">
```

Ideally on clicking the button the window should close or pop out a confirmation box.

As in the previous issue, I see this issue in IE11, Chrome, Mozilla browsers.

Closing functionality is working fine in IE 10 and other lower versions.

Are both issues related and is it due to any jQuery (jquery-1.7.1.js) that is used.

Comment: can you please add a fiddle here :)

Comment: I believe one of your scripts add that style, change class of the div and try again :)

Answer (score 1):

Some Jquery is doing that :- Try doing this :-

```
.NAVBUTTON {
display: block!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks C-Link, Anup for your quick replies. Adding !important solved the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your codebehind to find whether the button has `btnId.Visible = false;` attribute or inline style `Visible="false"`. Also, please check whether the visibility of the button hidden through javascript/jquery. There is no other reason than this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class or id selector `(. or #)`

By seeing this:

```
element.style {
display: none;
}
```

It is caused by some script so try to use `display: block;` to your button

jQuery solution:

```
$('.NAVBUTTON').css('display','block','important');
```

---

Also make sure you have not missed the `.` or `#` in NAVBUTTON in css.

Answer (score 0):

if NAVBUTTON is class applied to element  try this code
    .NAVBUTTON {
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: Segoe UI;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     font-variant: normal;
     line-height: normal;
     text-align: center;
     height: 25px;
     width: 120px;
     display:block ;!important
     }

if NAVBUTTON is Id applied to element try this code
     #NAVBUTTON {
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: Segoe UI;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     font-variant: normal;
     line-height: normal;
     text-align: center;
     height: 25px;
     width: 120px;
     display:block ;!important
    }